# How to solve for a vector in the following equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Suppose that we have vectors $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{x}_k$ which are $2\times1$ in dimension. I want to solve for $\vec{a}$ in the following:

\begin{equation}
  \sum_{k=1}^N(\vec{a}^T\vec{x}_k)\vec{x}_k = \sum_{k=1}^N(\vec{b}^T\vec{x}_k)\vec{x}_k
\end{equation}

**Here is my attempt:**
\begin{equation}
  \sum_{k=1}^N\vec{a}^T\vec{x}_k = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^N(\vec{b}^T\vec{x}_k)\vec{x}_k}{\sum_{k=1}^N\vec{x}_k}
\end{equation}

I'm stuck here, I'm not sure how to bring the $\vec{a}$ out of this.

Comment: This habit of writing the little arrows above the symbols to denote vectors is rather nasty.

Comment: Just curious, why's that :O

Comment:               - .

Comment: @user259242 What's your preferred way of denoting vectors?

Comment: @user259242 Ah, my lecture notes used this notation so I just stuck with it :P

Comment: @TroyG the usual way of denoting vectors is something like: let $V$ be a vector space over $k$. A vector is an element $v\in V$.